# Can you use yeast that is 2 years old if it has never been opened and has been in the freezer

Tags: bread

Is yeast that is two years old and has never been opened be used

Comment: Related: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/22690/does-nutritional-yeast-expire-or-go-bad

Answer (score 12):

If I were you, I'd do a simple test that determines, how *active* (= alive) your yeast is.

When you supply yeast with ideal living conditions, you can observe the activity - or lack of - as the yeast bubbles and foams.

For a test, you sprinkle yeast in lukewarm water and check for activity. A detailed description can be found [here](http://redstaryeast.com/yeast-baking-lessons/yeast-shelf-life-storage/yeast-freshness-test/), for example.

This should give you the answer whether your yeast is still useable or not.

Answer (score 0):

Well I just used a 7rys expired yeast that was vacuumed packed and rose my my baking buns and pizza.  it bubbled when I tested it. Go figure

Comment: Welcome to the site - yes, vacuum packed and dehydrated/freeze-dried yeast will keep quite a long time, so long as the packaging is OK, this is because the yeast is induced into a spore-like state, which is quite stable.

Answer (score -3):

No it wont work. I tried many a times with 2 years old dry yeast and it didnt work at all. Finally I came to the conclusion that old yeasts create more mess and wastage